# Google keywords comparison tool

Tags: seo, google, keywords

Is there a Google tool to check or to compare two keywords? I would like to know if "string1" is more searched than "string2".

Or how many times "string1" is search in last 30 days, or something like this.

Comment: Google offers the [Keyword Planner](https://ads.google.com/home/tools/keyword-planner/) tool as part of their Google Ads platform. It lists keywords and phrases by average monthly searches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Trends is the tool you are looking for. To compare the interest over time in bananas vs apples for example, view https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?q=banana,apple.